# How to count clicks on pinterest's 'Pin it' button?

Tags: javascript, pinterest

I want to count the clicks on a pinterest `Pin It` button in my shop.

I am not interested in counting actual pins, just the clicks on the button.

Is there any way to do this, given that the button is loaded into an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

this is the best i can do

```
$$('iframe').each(function(s){ var src=s.readAttribute('src');console.log(src.match(/pin/))})
```

then you can bind an event or there's this article which needs translating

http://web-analytics.altima.fr/blog/2012/06/28/le-tracking-analytics-des-partages-pinterest-est-possible/

but the way i load the file prevents me and possibly you from implementing this if your using code like this

```
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url= etc ... 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

if you can find a easy way round this would be appreciated

*** just found this very useful page
http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2012/03/12/tracking-pinterest-event-tracking/